# Как в C++ реализовать в функции обработку исключений с выводом текста при исключении

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, исключения

Необходимо подсчитать квадратный корень числа, при этом если число отрицательное то нужно бросить исключение. Если было создано исключение, то функция должна вывести текст. Всё это нужно завернуть в одну функцию.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double sq(int);

int main() {
     cout<<sq(-1);

return 0;
}

double sq(int a) {
    try {
        if (a < 0)
            throw - 1;
        return sqrt(a);
    }
    catch (int) {
        cout<< "Error";
    }
}
```

При запуске функции sq с аргументом -1 и попытке вывести её результат вместо "Error" выводится "Error0". Как это исправить, чтобы функция выводила просто "Error"?

Comment: А подумайте, откуда нуль-то берется?

Comment: Вынесите обработку исключения за пределы функции sq. (в main).

Comment: Да, если вынести catch из функции, то программа корректно работает. Вот только непонятно из-за чего выводится ноль и можно ли как-то вместить всё именно в функцию sq

Comment: Откуда берется 0 - ну ведь у вас функция должна что-то вернуть? Ведь у неё сигнатура `double sq(int a){}`. А вы из функции не вышли - исключение обработали внутри неё и дошли до закрывающей скобки. Наверняка компилятор написал предупреждение, что вы ничего не возвращаете в функции, которая должна вернуть `double`. Вам нужно определиться - что будет возвращать функция если произошло исключение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо обрабатывать исключение в `sq` - смысла нет: и без него вы просто можете вернуть "ничто".

Правильная обработка скорее такая:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double sq(int);

int main() {
    try {
        cout<<sq(-1);
    catch (int) {
        cout<< "Error";
    }
}

double sq(int a) {
    if (a < 0) throw - 1;
    return sqrt(a);
}
```

Так вы передаете обработку той функции, котоая может это сделать. В вашем варианте ваш код `sq` и тот, что ниже, эквавалентны:

```
double sq(int a) {
    if (a < 0) cout<< "Error";
    else return sqrt(a);
}
```

С той же ошибкой - отсутствием возвращаемого значения.